# Issue with Gatsby Netlify Form not receiving Submissions

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, ajaxform, netlify-form

I got the Netlify form working and accepting submissions but once I started setting up AJAX according to https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/, I can't figure out why submissions aren't being received.

Things I've tried:

1. Removing Hidden "form-name" input
2. Removing Recaptcha
3. Running "gatsby clean"
4. Removing opening Form tag's method attribute (method: "POST")
5. Removing action attribute from the opening Form tag and setting it directly in handleSubmit:
   .then(() => navigate("/thank-you/"))

Any suggestions or fixes are really appreciated!

**contact-form.js:**

```
import React, { setState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import Recaptcha from "react-google-recaptcha"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
import { Button, Col, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap"
import { breakpoints } from "../utils/breakpoints"

const RECAPTCHA_KEY = process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_KEY

export default function ContactForm() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({})
  const recaptchaRef = React.createRef() // new Ref for reCaptcha
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = React.useState(true)

  const handleChange = e => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  const encode = data => {
    return Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join("&")
  }
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target
    const recaptchaValue = recaptchaRef.current.getValue()

    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({
        "form-name": "contact",
        "g-recaptcha-response": recaptchaValue,
        ...state,
      }),
    })
      .then(() => navigate(form.getAttribute("action")))
      .catch(error => alert(error))
  }
  return (
    <Form
      name="contact"
      method="POST"
      netlify
      action="/thank-you"
      netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
      data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <Row>
        <Col md={12}>
          <h3>Message Us</h3>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Form.Group hidden>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="bot-field">
              Bot Field: Humans do not fill out!
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control name="bot-field" />
            <Form.Control name="form-name" value="contact" />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="first-name">First Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              size="lg"
              type="text"
              name="first-name"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="last-name">Last Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              size="lg"
              type="text"
              name="last-name"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="email">Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              size="lg"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="phone">Phone (Optional)</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              size="lg"
              type="tel"
              name="phone"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col md={12}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor="message">Message</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              required
              as="textarea"
              rows="3"
              placeholder="Enter your message here."
              name="message"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col md={12}>
          <FormControls>
            <Recaptcha
              ref={recaptchaRef}
              sitekey={RECAPTCHA_KEY}
              size="normal"
              id="recaptcha-google"
              onChange={() => setButtonDisabled(false)} // disable the disabled button!
              className="mb-3"
            />
            <div>
              <Button className="mr-3" type="reset" value="Eraser">
                Clear
              </Button>
              <Button type="submit" disabled={buttonDisabled}>
                Send
              </Button>
            </div>
          </FormControls>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  )
}
const FormControls = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  @media ${breakpoints.sm} {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  button[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
```

**gatsby-config:**

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `...`,
    description: `...`,
    author: `...`,
  },
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,     
  },
}
```

**HTML File in Static Folder:**

```
<form
  data-netlify="true"
  name="contactVivaz"
  method="POST"
  data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
  data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
>
  <input type="text" name="first-name" />
  <input type="text" name="last-name" />
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <input type="tel" name="phone" />
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state management looks good, what it's mandatory is to have (and to check) the input value of hidden fields that must match exactly the form name in the JSX as well as in the Netlify's dashboard. Assuming that everything is well named, as it seems, I believe your issue comes from the `Form` component, which should looks like:

```
<Form
  name="contact"
  method="POST"
  action="/thank-you"
  data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
  data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
  data-netlify="true"
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
```

Note the `data-netlify-honeypot` and `data-netlify` value.

For adding the reCAPTCHA field, you have two options:

- Allowing Netlify to handle all the related logic by adding simply an empty `<div>` like:

  ```
      <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"/>
  ```
- Adding a custom reCAPTCHA (your case) what required to add the [environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/gatsby/#gatsby-build-plugin) in your Netlify dashboard (prefixed with `GATSBY_`) and sending the response with the `g-recaptcha-response` field so your `POST` request needs to have that field as the [docs](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/spam-filters/#custom-recaptcha-2) suggest:

  > The Netlify servers will check the submissions from that form, and
  > accept them only if they include a valid g`-recaptcha-response` value.

Further references to base your setup:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/building-a-contact-form/
- https://www.seancdavis.com/blog/how-to-use-netlify-forms-with-gatsby/
- https://medium.com/@szpytfire/setting-up-netlify-forms-with-gatsby-and-react-5ee4f56a79dc

Comment: Hi Ferran, thank you for your suggestion! I changed my Form tag accordingly and also tried changing my form name to contactVivaz and the value in the hidden input field. The form in Netlify loads the new form and also displays "Extra spam prevention enabled via reCAPTCHA 2 and honeypot field." I'm not sure still but I'll explore the reference links and note any discrepancies.

Comment: It's still not receiving verified submissions. Is there any other solutions that may be worth trying?

Comment: Try removing the recaptcha (make it simple) and all related code and try it again

Comment: I removed all recaptcha references and it works. But how would I go about adding in recaptcha?

Comment: I just tried adding an html hidden form file to my static folder. The code is below:

<!-- A little help for the Netlify post-processing bots -->
<form
  name="contactVivaz"
  netlify
  netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
  data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
  hidden
>
  <input type="text" name="first-name" />
  <input type="text" name="last-name" />
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <input type="tel" name="phone" />
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
</form>

Comment: It looks like it's getting picked up in the build (below) but still no verified or spam submissions. 
4:52:09 PM: Post processing - HTML
4:52:09 PM: Processing form - contactVivaz
4:52:09 PM: Detected form fields:
4:52:09 PM:  - bot-field
4:52:09 PM:  - first-name
4:52:09 PM:  - last-name
4:52:09 PM:  - email
4:52:09 PM:  - phone
4:52:09 PM:  - message
4:52:09 PM: Post processing - header rules

Comment: Try editing your answer rather than pasting it here, please. It's impossible to read. You are not adding the environment variables in your Netlify dashboard (at least not well, needs to be prefixed with `GATSBY_` to allow Netlify to catch them and in addition, you needs to send the value for the reCAPTCHA in the request with the key `g-recaptcha-response` since you are adding a custom reCAPTCHA field, not the default one.

Comment: The environment variable was declared as a const at the top of contact-form.js with the GATSBY_ prefix. Sorry about the mess, wasn't sure of the best way to share that information.

Comment: Among getting the environment variable in the page, it needs to be set also in the Netlify dashboard as well.